# Convert Array into Object + setting propertie names

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got an Object with variable propertie names and im converting it into an array:

```
var test = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj); //[a, b, c]
```

Now I've got my array of Property names.
The next step I want to take is to turn this array into an Array of objects like this:

```
newObj= [ { "name": a }, {"name": b} , {"name" : c }]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilize `Array.prototype.map` - it transforms sequence into a new array by applying a function to each item, which is wrapping to an object with `name` property in your case:

```js
var names = ["a", "b", "c"];
var newObj = names.map(function(n) { return { name: n }; });

console.log(newObj);
```

Combining with your `getOwnPropertyNames` usage, it can look like:

```
var newObj = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).map(function(n) { return { name: n }; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` itself)

```js
var obj =  { a :1, b:2, c:3 };
var output = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).map( function( key ){  
  return { "name" : obj[ key ] } ;
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach without `getOwnPropertyNames` function(using `Object.keys` function):

```
// obj is your initial object
var newArr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return { name: k }; });
```